# POST Json to Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I've problem get JSON to Laravel

```
public function finish(Request $request)
{
    $data = Input::all();
    dd($data['transaction_status']);
}
```

But I get

[image]

Please help me

Comment: The key is not present. dd($data) and you can see all the data in it.

Comment: hi @KinshukLahiri but I want see data on transaction_status. What I need to do?

Comment: U can use $request -> all()

Comment: Hi @MyatHtut I mean, I want to only see data in transaction_status

Comment: @rizkyZulkarnaen  pls try $data=$request->all(); $data[‘transaction_status’];

Comment: hi @MyatHtut, I only want dd or var_dump $data[‘transaction_status’]; but get error

Comment: Your error says it all. Array doesnt contain key `transaction_status`.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the JSON payload from $request object use :

```
dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
```

Comment: you should not need to `json_decode()` as this is done by Laravel automatically

Comment: I already use json_decode, but get error json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @rizkyZulkarnaen Please try with only :  $data = $request->getContent();

Comment: Hi bro @dvl333 I only want show field  transaction_status, not all data

Comment: @rizkyZulkarnaen 
Could you please also try with :   
 `$transactionStatus= $request->json()->all()['transaction_status'];`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function finish(Request $request)
{
    $data = Input::all();
    dd($request->transaction_status);
}
```

*Updated Answer*

```
public function finish(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Input::all();
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

Comment: I only get null bro

Comment: @rizkyZulkarnaen: Give me  result of my updated answer